# How can I assign a group every single permission?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

Is there any way to assign all permissions to a certain group without doing it individually? I want to make it so that on my Bukkit server, Head Admin and over have all commands automatically and no need for OP.

Answer (score 1):

After the permissions rework, this is not possible without the use of an external permissions mod.

However, I'd like to note that this is NOT a good idea. In fact, this is why the ability to give the * permission was removed in the rework.

Some plugins will use permissions not as a way to enable commands but as a way to enable certain features, which you may not want. I could for instance make a permission like `antiCheat.user.preventFlying` that would stop anyone with the permission from flying. This would be desirable for ordinary users but potentially undesirable for admins.

Comment: Fun fact, the * node only gives permissions to players IF that permission is located in the plugin.yml file of each plugin. So for example the anticheat node you gave, the * node will not be affected since anticheat does not list `antiCheat.user.preventFlying` in the plugin.yml inside the antiCheat.jar

Comment: @aman207 My information is a little bit outdated and was never that in-depth to begin with. Thanks for the addendum :)